# real life people queue data structure

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, queue, hashset

How would you go about modeling a real life people queue?

Considering these main constraints:
- first in, first out
- at any time a random element can leave the queue
- pop should always return an element still in the queue
- any element in the queue is univocally identifiable ( eg. social security number )

The best solution I came out with is maintaining both a queue for the fifo constraint and an hash set to manage people that leaves. When I push an element in the queue I also push it in the hash-set. When I pop an element from the queue I also check in the hash set. If the element was removed before the pop I discard it and pop the next element. If the element is still in the hash-set I process the element then remove it from the hash-set. 
with this scenario push-and-add, pop-and-remove, remove-only operations should all be O(1) in time or am I wrong?

I'm feeling lucky that there is a more efficient or more elegant solution

Comment: You might ask yourself how important it is to have O(1) removal. If removal happens infrequently (which is true for "real life" queues), using a traditional FIFO queue with O(n) removal probably won't affect the overall running time of your program. There's much to be said for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

A problem I see with your solution is that you never seem to remove elements from the hash-set (unless I'm missing something), which is bad - although it would be expected O(1) per operation, the memory usage would be ever-increasing, regardless of how many people are in the queue.

I'd probably have turned it on its head:

Have the hash-map (of person to iterator in the queue) of all people in the queue.

For enqueue, you'd add to the map as well, for dequeue, you'd remove from the map as well.

For remove, since the hash-map contains the iterator you can remove the person from both the hash-map and the queue in the case of a remove operation. This assumes the queue is implemented as a (double) linked-list, and would still be O(1).

If you're not familiar with iterators, it's basically just a reference or pointer to the applicable node in the linked-list.

Comment: For the first problem you mention when I pop the queue I can also remove the element from the hash-set if it's still there in O(1).

Comment: If I use a hash-map with person to position in the queue ( is that what you mean? ) I need to update all subsequent values in the hash-map after removing an element wich is O(n)

Comment: Yours will still take O(1) time, but the space would be ever-increasing. Not position - think more like a reference or pointer to the node in the linked-list - so you don't need to update any other values after removal.

Comment: Well I think with references It'll be just fine.

Comment: I still don't get how can there be any difference between hash-set and hash-map for the ever-increasing space that you mention ( sorry if I'm missing some basic knowledge, I've only little experience with data structures )

Comment: It's more than just the difference between hash-set and hash-map. For your approach, all removals are added to the hash-set. So, after a million removals, there'd be a million people in the hash-set, even if there's only 5 people in the queue at that time. For my approach, the number of people in the hash-map are the same as the number of items in the queue. So after 2 million enqueues, a million dequeues and a million removals, there'd be no items left in the queue or the hash-map.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an "ordinary" queue which holds references to items that can be invalidated.  If an attempt to get the next item yields one which has been deleted, ignore that item and proceed to the next until a non-deleted item is found or the queue is empty.  The amount of memory wasted by this approach will be bounded by the ratio of items entering the queue to items fetched from the front.  If one wishes to avoid the possibility of unbounded memory waste, one could count the number of items added, invalidated, and removed and, if the number of items in the queue exceeds e.g. five times the number of still-valid items plus 1000, lock the queue, enqueue a marker, and then retrieve and re-enqueue items until that marker is encountered.

Comment: You are suggesting to make a queue of couples ( key , validity ) but how can I invalidate a random element in the queue in O(1) ?

Comment: @Luky: The queue would hold *references* to objects.  When a person is added to the queue, give the caller a reference to the object to which the queue holds a reference (you may wish to make all members of the object, except for an `Invalidate` method, `internal` so that outside code couldn't do anything with the object except invalidate it).  Alternatively, you could keep a `Dictionary` that maps ID numbers to the aforementioned items, add things to the dictionary when they enter the queue, and remove them when they are fetched or invalidated.